# Azure Free licensing

Tags: azure

I have two account Azure FREE MSDN account and Azure Enterprise account.
Can I combine the Azure Free and Enterprise License with one account
so that I can start using only one account and switch between subscriptions
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Due to authentication requirements and licensing we cannot do that, thats what I heard from one the MSFT team members just now.